# Convertion of special characters to unicode c++

Tags: c++, utf-8, special-characters, decode, icu

Currently, I have this character `°` (a degree symbol), that I need to convert it to `/00B0`. I noticed that there is a library called ICU for C/C++, but will I need to use such library?  My input is encoded as ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Does the general C++ libraries have this DECODE function already implemented or is the ICU library needed for such operations?

If there is such a method to call upon a character such as `°` please forward me to such or write up a quick example? :).

**EDIT** So I cycle through an entire line and when I see a special character, or rather some character that isn't an alpha character, digit character, '-' character, or ' ' character, I ask for the output of the character that didn't pass any of those tests.

I get an output like `\303` which is an OCTAL format of the special character. heres the code I use to do the tests:

```
if (isalpha(aline[i+1]) || isdigit(aline[i+1]) || aline[i+1] == '-' || aline[i+1] == ' ')
   regionName.push_back(aline[i+1]);
else
   cout << aline[i+1] << endl;
```

So when the else statement is executed, I get octal outputs... by default... How would I change that to unicode format?

Example output:

```
\303
\203
\302
```

Comment: "I get octal outputs..." as in, it literally prints `\303`?

Comment: yeah... the output sends back those values for some reason :/

Comment: when the else statement is executed, I either get upsidedown questionmarks (found a whitespace), or a '\' with three digits preceding

Comment: Must be conversion by the C++ library then. I'm guessing you're running on some sort of unix, so you'll need to (manually) convert the character to UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, Im using xcode on my mac

Comment: So theres not standard header/library/method in C++ I can use?

Comment: There's `wcstombs`, but it needs a wide string (`wchar_t *`).

Comment: What is the type of `aline`?  What are the _contents_ of `aline`?  What is the encoding of `aline`?  What compiler and OS?  Where is the output going (a file, or which terminal?)  Can you please edit this information into the question?

Comment: @jsetting32 Also, you're going to need to learn about what unicode _is_: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Are all those questions necessary? The original question i ask is stated... and it was basically asnwered by @Valentin. I also do know what unicode is... but I'm unfamiliar with C++ to this extent... I probably shouldn't even be using c++ at this point... python or some scripting language would make my life alot easier.

Comment: @jsetting32: You mean valentin's answer which reads: "what do you mean by that? Do you have it in a file? Do you read it from console? In both cases [What is the encoding?]"

Comment: @jsetting32: The main problem is: `aline[i+1]` is not a unicode character.  It's a byte.  Depending on the encoding, a unicode letter can be anywhere from one to over twenty bytes, (though it's usually two or three).  Also, I can't imagine any combination of bytes that would cause a terminal to display "`\303`", that has to be some Macintosh thing I never heard of.

Comment: Probably just a mac thing... oh well, ill just use ICU to asnwer my issue, since that was the original Q

Comment: nvm, sorry for being an ass @Mooing Duck, was just frustrated... but I didn't have to use ICU, just had to implemented a method to encode a special character, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, heres the answer I needed :) works great!!

include the following libraries:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
```

and pass any string you like to the function, it will encode all characters that are 'special'

```
static string EncodeNonASCIICharacters (std::string value)
{
    ostringstream stringBuilder;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
    {

        unsigned int character = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&(value[i]));
        if (character > 127)
        {
            stringBuilder << "\\u";
            stringBuilder << setw(4) << hex << setfill('0') << character;
        } else {
            string aValue;
            aValue += value[i];
            stringBuilder << aValue;
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.str();
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is interpreting input as encoded with the ISO/IEC 8859-1 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic things when it comes to `UNICODE`.

1. reading characters
2. storing characters in memory
3. writing/displaying characters

In unicode-applications the strings are usually stored as 2-byte characters.
For 1 and 3 there is nothing in plain C++. For Point 2 standard C++ library offers you a class wstring for storing characters as 2-byte strings.

If you say "I have the char" what do you mean by that? Do you have it in a file? Do you read it from console? In both cases you have to know the encoding of your input source.

When displaying the char, you have to be sure, your GUI library can handle the unicode.

So basic steps in pseudo-code are:

```
 char* myData = "some local-encoding data";
 MyUnicodeCapableStrincClass myString = MyUnicodeCapableStrincClass::fromsomeLocalEncoding( myData );
 MyUnicodeCapableGuiTextControl.setText( myString );
```

Knowing this, you should find the code example in ICU documentation faster, I hope.
I was not aware of ICU till now. (I'm using Qt - there the unicode is included since 1998.)

Comment: @DrewMcGowenL answer was filled out

Comment: Apperently [Qt is being altered to use ICU as a backend](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-ICU)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Wow, interesting! I'm going to check it. Thanks!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Sorry, first I've submitted unfinished answer. I only wanted to add a line break :-(

Comment: "In unicode-applications the strings are usually stored as 2-byte characters" That's not true at all. Every GTK+/GNOME application supports unicode through utf-8. Qt and MS are too incompetent on the matter to the point they say "unicode" without describing what actual encoding is being used; that's why we will forever have those sort of confused questions and confusing answers.

Comment: @DanielKO: It is not a feature of GTK, it is a bug :-) I remember, I came across this absurdity in a Mono project, which used some GTK libraries. GTK docu names using C-string functions with UTF-8 as a big feature. In practice calling strlen() on a utf-8 string is always a confusion - the result is mostly unexpected. UNICODE is actually the ability to encode any character of any language. UTF-8 is for serializing/de-serializing UNICODE-characters - thus "Unicode Transformation Format"

Comment: OP has clarified input is ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: utf16 has the same bugs with wcslen that utf8 has with strlen